# Unable to match results that contain apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db table that contains some business names.

I need to query by name and usually have no problems unless the name contains an apostrophe.

```
("
SELECT*
FROM t1
WHERE bus_name = '".$busName."' 
")
```

I've experimented and tried using static value, like this:

```
("
SELECT*
FROM t1
WHERE bus_name = \"Bob's store\" 
")
```

and it worked. Tried:

```
("
SELECT*
FROM t1
WHERE bus_name = \"".$busName."\" 
")
```

and it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Prepared statements and bound parameters?

Comment: You have to escape the content of the argument, not the quote chars. So either do it manually by using one of the escape functions offered by your php mysql extension, or, preferred, learn about the benefits of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Answer (score 1):

You should [prepare the query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), here is an example using PDO

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT*
FROM t1
WHERE bus_name = :busName
");
$stmt->bindValue(':busName', $busName);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Hmm, I already use a library to access the db: $bus = $db->get_row("
SELECT*
FROM t1
WHERE bus_name = '".$busName."' 
"); How do I combine it with this PDO?

Comment: Well your library needs to prepare the query, which extension does it use pdo or mysqli

Comment: @santa - what library are you using?

Comment: Pretty old one, called ezsql

Comment: I dont know this library, to escape the single quote do `$busName = str_replace("'", "''", $busName);`

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements for this ( or any ) case.

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE foo = :foo');

$stmt->bindValue(':foo', "foo ' bar");
$stmt->execute();
```

Your source at its current state is vulnerable against Command Injections ( SQL Injection ).